# classpath does not default to current directory

Tags: java

I wrote and compiled a simple Hello World program in Java but when I tried to run it I was greeted with the error message `Error: Could not find or load main class Hello`. It was only after I executed the command `java -cp . Hello` that it successfully ran.

Oddly enough, the current directory already seems to be part of the classpath. The script

```
class CheckClassPath{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
    }
}
```

prints `.`, though I again have to explicitly set the `classpath` option.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and open-JDK version 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that a `CLASSPATH` environment variable has been set.  Run `echo $CLASSPATH` to see what it is set to.

If you don't use the `-jar` option then:

- If there is a `-cp`, that specifies the classpath
- Else if `CLASSPATH` is set in the environment, that specifies the classpath
- Else a default classpath of "." is used.

Comment: Yes, it appears that Intel VTune sets a global CLASSPATH variable.